# Is writing data in shared memory blocked in android platform?

Tags: android, android-ndk

In Android native I have created Shared Memory using API ashmem_create_region like

```
fd = ashmem_create_region("SharedRegionName", 1024);
char* base_address = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

This creates native **int fd** which I have passed to application.

Inside application I am trying to write 128 bytes to this shared memory which failed to  write and return write len = 0.

```
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.adoptFd(native.getFD());
    Log.d(TAG, "pfd : "+pfd );
    FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fd);
    FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bytebuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128);
        for (int i=0; i<128; i++) {
           bytebuf.put((byte)(i));
    }

    try {
      int len = fc.write(bytebuf);
      Log.d( TAG, "fc.len "+len);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Logs are :-
pfd : {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[51]}

fc.len 0

I am not sure but looks like platform is not permitting or blocking to write on shared Memory, If anybody has tried can you please confirm or please let me know if something is wrong in this process.

Comment: Do you have the permission to write file in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Which permission, Do I need to add any permission while creating and writing to shared Memory.

Comment: Permission for reading and writing files.

Comment: The shared memory is the pointer you got back from `mmap`.  If all you want to do is write data to a file descriptor, create a pipe instead.

Comment: @eozgonul We dont give any permission in android for file write, its permission for external storage.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />